# How does the なら particle work in the sentence [地獄なら知っている]?

Tags: grammar, particles

A recent episode of *Re: Zero* is titled *地獄なら知っている*, when I watched the preview I could not understand exactly what it meant but  when I finally saw the translation, they translated it as "I know hell" but the literal translation is as far as I know: "If hell, I know". Furthermore, in the context of the episode, the main character says the phrase "地獄なら知っている" in order to indicate that he has been through hell/knows what suffering is.

How does the なら particle work in this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 地獄なら知っている

is just saying, "if it's hell, I know it".

なら is one of a number of ways Japanese has to express the English notion of "if" and conditionals.